# Is it possible to set bits while creating a BitSet?

Tags: java

I need to create a few BitSets in a loop, something like:

```
ArrayList<BitSet> bitSetList = new ArrayList<BitSet>();

for (int x : array) {
    bitsetList.add(new BitSet() //and set bits in specific places)
}
```

Comment: Create the array with multiple items in it ?

Comment: What array? I mean the BitSet item. I edited the post added the looping array btw

Comment: oh ok, yes it's more clear now.

Comment: Sure, but doing it all in one line is not practical.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thank you. So I need to create the new BitSet in a line before, set the bits and only then add it. Becuase the original code added long arrays so it could be done in one line, i.e  `array.add(new long[]{(1L << bit3), // ...)`

Answer (score 5):

(To create a BitSet & set specific bits,) You can use one of:

- ```
  static BitSet valueOf(byte[] bytes) /** 
   Returns a new bit set containing all the bits in the given byte array.**/
  ```
- ```
  static BitSet valueOf(long[] longs) /**
   Returns a new bit set containing all the bits in the given long array.*//
  ```
- ```
  static BitSet valueOf(ByteBuffer bb) /**
   Returns a new bit set containing all the bits in the
   given byte buffer between its position and limit.**/
  ```
- ```
  static BitSet valueOf(LongBuffer lb) /**Returns a new bit set containing all the bits in the
   given long buffer between its position and limit.**/
  ```

API-DOC: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html

Comment: This one looks good. I am actually converting my code to use BitSet instead of long arrays. So if my original code was: `array.add(new long[]{bit1), (bit2), ...)`, I can do something like 
`BitSet bitSet = newBitSet(); array.add(bitSet.valueOf(new long[]{bit1), (bit2), ...))`?

Comment: Thx! ;) Please refer to "More precisely," part of the javadoc, if some conversion appears needed! ..unfortunately (I'd like it!) there is no: `valueOf(boolean[])` ;)

Comment: Ahh thank you! I'm trying to convert this code: https://blackflux.wordpress.com/2014/04/30/peg-solitaire-brute-force/ to fit boards more than 64 cells, and converting all from `long` to `BitSet`i s hard for a beginner like me, I'm on it for a few days already. Will try some more ! :D

Answer (score 3):

`BitSet` has several static overloaded methods called `valueOf` with which you can create a `BitSet` initalized with the bits set in them, for example a `byte` array:

```
BitSet example = BitSet.valueOf(new byte[] { 0b101 });
System.out.println(example.get(0)); // Prints true
System.out.println(example.get(1)); // Prints false
System.out.println(example.get(2)); // Prints true
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf(byte%5B%5D)

Answer (score 1):

Like any other object in Java, you can create a BitSet object and add it to a List in this manner. Before adding it to the List, I would create the BitSet object and add data to the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can you stream to create a `BitSet` of each ints like that:

```java
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 8, 15);
List<BitSet> list = ints.stream().map(BitSet::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

The `.map(BitSet::new)` can be replaced by `.map(i -> new BitSet(i))` if you don't like how it's wrote.

Comment: The constructor only sets the initial size of the `BitSet`, it doesn't set its value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `BitSet.valueOf()`. Just to merry this post. Here is a mess hack.

```java
ArrayList<BitSet> bitSetList = new ArrayList<BitSet>();
        
bitSetList.add(new BitSet() {
    public BitSet setMultiple(final int[] bitArray) {
        for(int i=0; i < bitArray.length; ++i) 
            set(bitArray[i]);
        return this;
    };
}.setMultiple(array));
```